# Scripting app that can listen on notifications

Tags: notifications, scripts

I'm looking for an app that can run in the background, and listen for a silent notification from a different app (i.e. shows up on notification list but makes no sound) and once it appears, make a sound. Is there an app that I can script like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download MacroDroid Pro from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid), install it and open it. Back to settings and allow it in the following aspects:

1. Allow All Permissions about it in application settings
2. Allow Notification Access in notification settings
3. Allow Its Accessibility Service in accessibility settings
4. Allow Device Administration in security settings
5. Allow Usage Access in security settings and all other permissions it requests

Open it and

1. Click Add Macro
2. Notification Received Trigger and select which application you want notified for
3. Play Sound Action and select which sound you like notified for
4. Just leave an empty constraint since you want to be notified at all times or put instances to consider before the above happens
5. Save the macro and you're ready to go

The Macro Summary should look something just like this:

[image: automation-summarry]

You could have solved your problem